# É possível visualizar e restaurar os comentários removidos por nós mesmos?

Tags: suporte, comentários

Não achei a opção de visualizar os comentários removidos (como existe para respostas por exemplo). Existe? É possível restaurar um comentário meu que eu mesmo removi?

Comment: Resposta em forma de comentário: não.

Comment: Considere aceita. :)

Comment: **[✓](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4551/como-usar-o-s%c3%admbolo-de-aceito-num-coment%c3%a1rio)**

Comment: Dica: o cache do Google e o Internet Archive às vezes mostram os comentários já apagados.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Os comentários removidos são visíveis somente para os moderadores. Eles estão escondidos quando a página abre mas é-nos possível vê-los se quisermos.

Os moderadores podem ver e apagar todos os comentários. Podem também recuperar os seus próprios comentários e os comentários de outros utilizadores que o próprio moderador tenha excluído.