# Como usar o símbolo de "aceito" num comentário?

Tags: suporte, formatação, comentários

Eu já vi por aí, mas como era comentário não tinha como abrir a edição só pra ver como a mágica funcionava, e na hora nem pensei em perguntar. É com markdown, HTML, imagem? Acho que pode ser útil pra explicar pra novatos como aceitar uma reposta, mas no caso [é só pra fazer uma graça mesmo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4550/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-visualizar-e-restaurar-os-coment%C3%A1rios-removidos-por-n%C3%B3s-mesmos). rsrs

Comment: **[✔](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4551#comment14550_4551)** Os mais parecidos que eu achei foram esses: ✓ e ✔, basta _copy & paste_. O do começo da linha eu usei em _bold_ e com _link_ pra dar uma corzinha no bicho.

Comment: "É com markdown, HTML, imagem?" É apenas um caractere normal. [Check Mark (U+2713)](http://unicode-table.com/en/2713/).

Comment: ✅ Essa aqui tá esperando alguém clicar no _accept_. Versão _link: [✅](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4551) @mgibsonbr o U+2714 é mais "gordinho"

Comment: @Bacco Pois é, eu peguei o primeiro caractere do seu comentário e busquei, sem olhar o segundo. A propósito, esse outro que você acabou de postar é o [White Heavy Check Mark (U+2705)](http://unicode-table.com/en/2705/). Não que essa informação ajude muita coisa, já que o único jeito que sei de inserir num comentário é copiando e colando mesmo...

Comment: http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=check+mark ... Ao menos nao é o http://unicode-table.com/en/1F4A9/

Comment: U+2713 acho que era esse o que vi... ✓

Comment: @gustavo, será que rola docê consolidar os comentários numa resposta? [](https://web.whatsapp.com)

Comment: @brasofilo Não entendi, como assim? (esse QR era pra abrir um chat com vc no zap? Não abriu, mas gostei dele ^^ pelo menos agora posso usar o zap enquanto meu filho menor joga no meu cel hehe ...)

Comment: totalmente não relacionado, era só para marcar a origem do ícone ;)

Comment: hahaha Ok então. :)